# Error in importing Self defined module in Spyder 3.2.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Spyder 3.2.4
I have created module(or Folder) A and create the file name b.py. In b.py I have created `class B():`

Now I am importing above defined class in test.py

## test.py

from A import B
b=B()

I am getting error
`ImportError: cannot import name 'B'`

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: just use `from b import B` first b is filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File `a.py`:

```
from b import B
class A:
    def call():
        B.hello()
A.call()
```

File `b.py`:

```
class B:
    def hello():
        print("Hello")
```

Run `a.py` and output will be `Hello`, to import classes from another *.py files in python you need to use its filename as import source, e.g. **b** for `b.py`.

If you have folder and *.py files in it, and you want to import them you should use folder as set of modules, and file names as modules.

For example:

```
./A/b.py
./test.py
```

in test.py:

```
from A import b
b.B.hello()
```

`from A import b` imports whole b.py file, to import only `B` class you need to specify it in **from**:

```
from A.b import B
```

after that class `B` will be accessible without `b.B`

Comment: In my case, A is folder(module), b.py is python file, now I am creating another file say test.py. In test.py my first line of code is "from A import B" and second line of code is "b=B()" when I am running this I am getting error "ImportError: cannot import name 'B'", how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Then use `from A.b import B` to import class `B` from `A/b.py`.

Comment: Thanks from A.b import B is working

Comment: @RajeshPiryani Updated the answer, see it. (Accept as answer)